# How do I find out what Audio Device Codec my laptop have?

Tags: laptop, audio, codec

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop.

Now, usually, when you make a custom PC, you see something like ALC 892/897 Audio Device Codec name in motherboard specifications (that you are planning to use).

So laptops also have motherboards so I'm wondering how can I find out which ALC audio codec device my laptop has?

I managed to find out only these things in my laptop but it doesn't mention anything like ALC:

[image]

[image]

If I go to properties of any of these, it shows some device name but it's not clearly written e.g.,

[image]

Same is here, device name/codec is not clearly mentioned.

[image]

Lastly, dxdiag shows this, which also doesn't have what I'm looking for:

[image]

---

I feel all these settings are showing only driver or software names rather than anything about device.

Comment: @Gantendo I'm not sure. How to check it? Is it anything different from the settings what I've shared?

Comment: Note: What you are referring to as "Codec", is usually called a "soundcard". Maybe that information makes it easier for you to find what you are looking for.

Comment: @mashuptwice oh I wasn't sure.

Comment: This is not a “codec” question; this is a hardware question. As @mashuptwice explains, this is a “soundcard” spec you are you looking for.

Comment: Do you want to know for installing drivers or setting an output?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek mainly I want to compare the "audio quality" of my laptop of a PC (the motherboard I'm planning to buy precisely) I am planning to build.

But I want this comparison even before I buy the motherboard. So I guess knowing the codec name might give me idea if the motherboard audio that I'm planning to buy is good enough for me or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your laptop has a *Realtek ALC295* audio codec connected to the analogue output. You can see this in your device list as Realtek(R) Audio - Realtek is a known audio codec developer / manufacturer and it's device ID DEV_0295 identify it as the ALC295.

Having said that - ALC295 seems to be exclusively sold to motherboard manufacturers as an OEM part, so there's not that much information on actual capabilities of the hardware.

Furthermore, your device actually has three (digital) sound cards:

- The Realtek ALC 295 which most likely provides audio for speakers and audio jack.
- Intel Display Audio which most likely provides audio over HDMI/DisplayPort connection.
- nVidia Audio Device which would provide audio via HDMI/DisplayPort connection if your nVidia GPU would have such a connection (most likely it doesn't).

Comment: Does it also mean my laptop/motherboard doesn't have a physical sound card? Only ALC295 is a physical part?

Comment: The ALC295 is a physical soundcard - it can be either in a separate chip on motherboard (like on this Dell XPS 13 - the Realtek codec is the orange outlined chip in Step 15 - https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Dell+XPS+13+Teardown/36157#s81012 ) or embedded as part of other chips on the board.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. You mentioned my device has 3 digital sound cards, including ALC 295. Does digital sound card mean it's physical part or not?

Comment: It's a physical part in all cases - it's just that the Intel and nVidia ones can only provide digital output via HDMI/DisplayPort/USB-C connectors. This is why I mentioned (digital) in parenthesis.

The Realtek one however provides also the analogue output via DAC to drive speakers and headphone jack on your laptop.

Answer (score 8):

Something like "ALC 892/897" is a special audio chip connected to an Intel HDA compatible soundcard. It's called a codec because it **co**des and **dec**odes the digital data stream coming from the soundcard, and converts it to and from audio signals.

Most modern chipsets have an Intel HDA "soundcard" integrated into the chipset (after all, the point of having an external codec is that you just need a few extra pins to connect it to the standard chipset).

You can also have multiple codec chips (e.g., an analog and an HDMI codec) connected to a single HDA soundcard.

Now, even if it's integrated into the chipset, your motherboard doesn't have to use the Intel SDA soundcard. So if they have a different soundcard (like your Realtek one) which doesn't use external codec chips, then no actual "codec" will appear in the system information.

And this seems to be the case with your laptop, I'd guess the in-built sound connectors all go to the Realtek soundcard.

---

Finally, don't confuse Intel HDA codec chips with software codecs (the list in your first image) like MP3, MPEG, etc. These also **co**de and **dec**ode and digital data stream, but this is compressed audio, and coding and decoding happens purely in the CPU, by software.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some extra doubts that I wasn't aware of. What I understood from 1st 2 paragraphs is if a soundcard isn't integrated on motherboard, then it will need a separate codec chip to connect to a soundcard (we also need to add soundcard separately because it's not integrated)?

And if it *is* integrated, it doesn't need any extra codec chip? It means both "soundcard" and "codec chip" are integrated on the motherboard? 

Am I right?

Comment: No. There's a particular kind of soundcard (Intel HDA) that can have separate codec chips attached to. This "soundcard" is often integrated into the CPU/Southbridge chipset. Other soundcards can do whatever they want: have extra chips, or not, call them codec, call them something else. For Intel HDA, the codec is an extra chip on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to set device manager to "Devices by connection", which show what's connected to what. For reference, below is my laptop (Lenovo T14), attached to a docking station. The "Realtek(R) Audio" device is the on-board codec. Its hardware ID says `INTELAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0257&...` - not sure how that's different from your `HDAUDIO\...` hardware ID.

[image: Device manager - Devices by connection]